# In termux, how do I get vim python omnicomplete to work?

Tags: python, vim, code-completion, omnicomplete, termux

I'm using vim-python in termux. Onmicomplete completes nothing. I mean C-X, C-O does nothing. Not a single keyword, module, nothing. It always gives no pattern found.

```
$ pkg list-installed | grep vim        

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with 
caution in scripts.                      

vim-python/stable,now 8.1.2000 arm [installed]              
vim-runtime/stable,now 8.1.2000 all [installed]
```

My current  .vimrc is

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

".vimrc setup file

"turn on filetype recognition and plugin
"turn on filetype recognition and plugin
filetype plugin on
"enable omnicomplete
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete

nmap <Space> i_<Esc>r
```

From vim I see:

```
:set omnifunct
  omnifunc=python3complete#Complete
```

Nothing works out of the box. Syntax highlighting is installed just like on a normal Debian install.

I've installed python-mode. However it didn't work. I tried pydiction and it worked, but a simple

```
ab[tab]
```

Here, [tab] just means tapping the tab key, which is how pydiction works. It gave me abs( buried in a list of a dozen or more useless alternatives and similar for other functions and couldn't find

```
from bs4 import Be[tab]
```

At all.

Not sure it vim too scaled down in termux or what. I've not found another feature that hasn't worked out it.

Here are compiled options...

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep  7 2019 23:58:37)
Included patches: 1-1999
Compiled by builder@cirrus-ci-task-4815910415630336
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            -gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: arm-linux-androideabi-clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -Oz -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: arm-linux-androideabi-clang   -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -march=armv7-a -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm   -lncursesw -liconv     -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m/ -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -ldl -lm
```

Thank you in advance f any help

Comment: Hi! Do you use vim with python support anywhere else, besides Android?

Comment: Yes. I've not had this problem in those. My Linux on desktops and laptops is Debian.